# How to prevent deferred styling from loading every page load instead of only the first time?

Tags: html, css, performance, loading, deferred

I'm trying to enhance performance on a website. We're using deferred styling so only the critical CSS is loading at first and the rest of the CSS files load in after page load.

The problem here is that this happens on every page load. We want to create something that caches the loaded CSS files so it does not load the files on every page load.

How do I get my stylesheets to get cached by the browser?

We're using https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

```
 <noscript id="deferred-styles">
<link href="/css/rfs-styleguide.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/css/rfs-layout.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/css/rfs-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/css/rfs-icons-betalen.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/css/rfs-icons-algemeen.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/dist/rfs-responsive-template.css?{{cachebust}}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</noscript> 
<script>
var loadDeferredStyles = function () {
    var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
    var replacement  = document.createElement("div");
    replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(replacement)
    addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
};
var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(function () {
    window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0);
});
else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```

Comment: _“We're using deferred styling”_ - show us what that means. It could be a lot of things, so without seeing your actual implementation, I don’t see how we could even begin to answer this.

Comment: @misorude Sorry, i thought it was a common solution by Google. This is what we're using: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: All that does is put the `link` elements that are “hidden” inside the `noscript` element inside the document. If this doesn’t take the resources from the cache, but loads them again from the server, then this has very little to do with this script - you would have the same effect, if you didn’t do all that, and just embedded your stylesheets normally. So your actual question at this point then becomes how do I get my stylesheets to get cached by the browser, and for that you should do some research, if you don’t know about that topic yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem as you using the Google recommended deferral code. I tried running a prefetch request however it still was not caching it.

I found two ways to fix this, add the css code at the end of the html document (after final  tag). Not really ideal

Or you can use this script which I found here https://master-origin-loadcss.fgview.com/test/preload.html

```
<link rel="preload" href="slow.css.php" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

This will defer the CSS and cache it